# How to keep the selected row always visible in a HTML table which is periodically changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have cobbled together some Javascript and HTML that will enable me to select a table row.  It will also add some rows at the top periodically via a timer.  This is just a placeholder for an ajax call that will go in later.

I want the table to be scrollable, so there is a table inside of a scrollable `div`.  This works great, but might make the issue a little more complicated.

The issue I am having is that when new rows are populated at the top, I do not want the table to move to these new rows, I want the viewport of the table to stay the same.  If the selected row is not near the top, when new rows get populated this automatically happens.  However, if the selected row is near the top, when new rows get added they move the selected row off the screen.  I would like these to be added to the top, but not move/change the viewable area.

I have a jsFiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2575yLew/3/) that shows the issue. The code that adds the rows looks like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('#record_table tbody')                      // select table tbody
       .prepend('<tr class="table_row" />')       // prepend table row
       .children('tr:first')                      // select row we just created
       .append('<td class="td1">New row</td><td>New row data</td><td class="td3">more data</td>');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2575yLew/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the working code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var wasClicked = false;

$('#record_table tbody').on('click', '.table_row', function() {
    $('.table_row').removeClass('selected'); // "Unselect" all the rows
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // Select the one clicked
    wasClicked = true;  
    $('div.tbody.scrollit').scrollTop(  $('div.tbody.scrollit').scrollTop() + 1);
});

setInterval(heartbeat,10000);

function heartbeat() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $('#record_table tbody')                    // select table tbody
         .prepend('<tr class="table_row" />')       // prepend table row
         .children('tr:first')                      // select row we just created
         .append('<td class="td1">New row</td><td>New row data</td><td class="td3">more data</td>');  

        if (wasClicked) {
            $('tbody').animate({scrollTop: 22}, 1 );
        }
    }
}

});
```

What have I done?

First, I added the following line at the end of the for loop, that adds the rows:

```
 $('tbody').animate({scrollTop: 22}, 1 );
```

It moves the `scrollTop` 22 pixels, which is exactly the height of your `tr`'s, I propose that you get that value directly from the `css`, not `hardcoded`.

Second, I added a `bool` variable to check if a row is clicked (at the top):

```
var wasClicked = false;
```

and

```
wasClicked = true; //for validation to the on click function
```

and the validation with an IF statement within the for loop:

```
if (wasClicked) {
    $('tbody').animate({scrollTop: 22}, 1 );
}
```

Third, because it was not working when the scroll was at the top, added this lines to the on click function:

```
$('div.tbody.scrollit').scrollTop(  $('div.tbody.scrollit').scrollTop() + 1);
```

That line, moves the scroll one pixel so that all the code above works just fine.

Forgot to mention, you also must add some validation to prevent the user to non 
stop click on the same row, there is some movement there, but the row still does not leave the `viewpoint`.

Just check if the same row was again clicked on, and prevent the movement. that will not be to hard to implement.
Hope I could help.